# R: how to assign A[B[, j], j] without for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, vectorization, assign

I want to replace certain values in matrix `A` by another value: `1` in this case. For column j of `A` the row-indices that need to be replaced are those in the j*th* column of `B`. Below I give an example, where the assignment is achieved by a for-loop.

My question is: how could this assignment be achieved simpler, more efficient and/or without the for-loop?

```
set.seed(4521)
n <- 10
p <- 5

A <- matrix(rep(NaN,n*p),n,p)

B <- replicate(p, sample(n))
B <- B[1:5,]

for (j in 1:n){      
  A[B[,j],j] <- 1      
}

print(B)
print(A)
```

`B`:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5   10    7    6    5
[2,]   10    2    9    9    2
[3,]    7    9    3   10    4
[4,]    9    4    1    3    3
[5,]    4    8    6    4    9
```

`A`:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN
 [2,]   NaN    1  NaN  NaN    1
 [3,]   NaN  NaN    1    1    1
 [4,]     1    1  NaN    1    1
 [5,]     1  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
 [6,]   NaN  NaN    1    1  NaN
 [7,]     1  NaN    1  NaN  NaN
 [8,]   NaN    1  NaN  NaN  NaN
 [9,]     1    1    1    1    1
 [10,]    1    1  NaN    1  NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
A[cbind(as.numeric(B), as.numeric(col(B)))] <- 1
```

---

Thanks (and +1) to a typo in Zheyuan Li's first answer which had [`col`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/col.html) instead of `ncol`.

Answer (score 4):

We can use matrix indexing:

```
i <- as.numeric(B)
j <- rep(1:ncol(B), each = nrow(B))
A[cbind(i,j)] <- 1
```

Or put them in a single line:

```
A[cbind(as.numeric(B), rep(1:ncol(B), each = nrow(B)))] <- 1
```

---

As OP noted later by some dig-in himself, we can replace `rep(1:ncol(B), each = nrow(B))` by a shorter `as.numeric(col(B))`. I know it but I never do it, because it uses twice as much memory as the one I suggested. Which one to use is just a personal preference. It only matters when working on large matrices.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it is clearer what @Zheyuan Li's code is doing. I would prefer his solution.
Just to show an alternative: Using 1D indexing you could do:

```
An <- nrow(A)
Bp <- ncol(B)
offset <- rep(seq(0, An*(Bp-1), by=An), each=Bp)
A[B + offset] <- 1
```

In one line:

```
A[B + rep(seq(0, nrow(A)*(ncol(B)-1), by=nrow(A)), each=ncol(B))] <- 1
```